# How to install RabbitMq in AWS Linux AMI 2023?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, adobe, magento2.4

AWS Linux AMI 2023 doesn't support EPEL or EPEL-like repositories to install RabbitMQ and dependences.

So, how to install RabbitMQ and dependences in the new AWS Linux AMI 2023 with yum or dnf?

Need to install for the Adobe Commerce Community (Magento 2).

Tks!

Comment: Amazon Linux is derived from CentOS and there are [RPM packages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html) available.

Comment: in the link in the comment above, the example repo file under  "Red Hat 9, CentOS Stream 9, Rocky Linux 9, Alma Linux 9, Modern Fedora Releases" worked for me (it mentions it targets Amazon Linux 2023, among others). put it in /etc/yum.repos.d/rabbitmq.repo, install with `dnf install rabbitmq-server`, and it should install erlang and rabbit successfully

Answer (score 0):

Previously, on Amazon Linux 2, which was based on CentOs, you could add an Epel-Release repository and then install the corresponding package. On Amazon Linux 2023 this is not possible, as it is a Fedora-based OS, so Epel-Release is not supported. Here is a short article on the topic: https://linux.how2shout.com/can-we-install-epel-repo-on-amazon-linux-2023/.

However, this does not mean that installing the right package is not possible. One solution might be to use rpmfind.net to find a repository where the package of your choice is available. Take a look at https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=rabbitmq-server, for example. This way you can find the right RPM repository and try to install it using commands:

```
dnf config-manager --add-repo some-url/repository.repo
dnf config-manager --set-enabled some-repository
```

The second possible solution is to install the selected package using the URL:

```
dnf install -y https://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/releases/38/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/r/rabbitmq-server-3.11.10-1.fc38.x86_64.rpm
```

Note, however, that for security reasons it is best to use the official repositories.